# Is there a pure Promise-based approach for mapping/concatenating collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

### async vs. Q generally

I'm learning Node.js development, and trying to wrap my brain around strategies for managing asynchronous "callback hell".  The two main strategies I've explored are Caolan McMahon's [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, and Kris Kowal's promise-based [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) module.

Like [many other people](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/mWtqFE0spWk), I'm still struggling to understand when you should use one vs. the other.  However, generally speaking I have found promises and Q-based code to be *slightly* more intuitive, so I have been moving in that direction.

### Mapping/Concatenating collections generally

However, I'm still stuck using the async module's [functions for managing collections](https://github.com/caolan/async#collections).  Coming from a Java and Python background, most of the time when I work with a collection, the logic looks like this:

1. Initialize a new empty collection, in which to store results.
2. Perform a for-each loop with the old collection, applying some logic to each element and pushing its result into the new empty collection.
3. When the for-each loop ends, proceed to use the new collection.

In client-side JavaScript, I've grown accustomed to using jQuery's [map() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)... passing in that step #2 logic, and getting the step #3 result as a return value.  Feels like the same basic approach.

### Mapping/Concatenating collections with async and Q

The Node-side async module has similar [map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) and [concat](https://github.com/caolan/async#concat) functions, but they don't return the concatenated result back at the original scope level.  You must instead descend into the callback hell to use the result.  Example:

```js
var deferred = Q.defer();

...

var entries = [???]; // some array of objects with "id" attributes

async.concat(entries, function (entry, callback) {
    callback(null, entry.id);
}, function (err, ids) {
    // We now have the "ids" array, holding the "id" attributes of all items in the "entries" array.
    ...
    // Optionaly, perhaps do some sorting or other post-processing on "ids".
    ...
    deferred.resolve(ids);
});

...

return deferred.promise;
```

Since my other functions are becoming promise-based, I have this code returning a promise object so it can be easily included in a `then()` chain.

### Do I really need both?

The ultimate question that I'm struggling to articulate is: do I really need both async **and** Q in the code example above?  I'm learning how to replace the async module's control flow with Q-style promise chains generally... but it hasn't yet "clicked" for me how to do mapping or concatenation of collections with a promise-based approach.  Alternatively, I'd like to understand why you can't, or why it's not a good idea.

If async and Q are meant to work together as I am using them in the example above, then so be it.  But I would prefer not to require the extra library dependency if I could cleanly use Q alone.

(*Sorry if I'm missing something outrageously obvious.  The asynchronous event-driven model is a very different world, and my head is still swimming.*)

Comment: Could you please make your example actually asynchronous? Currently you're only doing a [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)

Comment: Hmm... as I said, I'm fairly new at this.  I have not yet worked with Underscore, but the documentation for "pluck" indicates that it is shorthand for one of the most common uses of "map".  When I use the async module's "map" or "concat" functions, they don't let me block and wait for the results to be returned in the original scope.  Instead, they make me pass a callback that will executed at some uncertain point.  Moreover, uhh... the name of the module is "async"!  So I'm pretty sure this is an asynchronous operation, even if it isn't a particularly interesting or exotic one.

Comment: Sure, I just commented on the example code that you posted above where you are calling `callback` *synchronously* in the callback function of `async.concat`. It would be better if you exchanged that for some asynchronous example function (without giving an implementation of that)

Comment: That is the coding style using by Caolan McMahon's async module.  I'm not sure if it is actually synchronous under the covers or not (although it sure would be odd/ironic if it is).  The *intention* is for the callback to be invoked asynchronously...  :)

Comment: No. If you don't have asynchronous code, then you don't need to use callbacks or the `async` module at all…

Comment: @StevePerkins I just wanted to add that the Bluebird library does this well out of the box. Also, it's faster. Like 100 times faster.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Do I really need both?

No. Mapping asynchronous iterators over a collection is quite simple with promises, but it requires two steps instead of one function call. First, the collection is [`map`ped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to an array of promises for the parallel iteration. Then, those promises are fed into [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) to make one promise for the mapped collection. In contrast to `async`, the order of the result is guaranteed.

```
var entries = […]; // some array of objects with "id" attributes

var promises = entries.map(function(object) {
    return asyncPromiseReturingFunction(object);
}); // the anonymous wrapper might be omitted
return Q.all(promises);
```

For `concat`, you would have to append a

```
.then(function(results) {
     return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], results);
});
```

Comment: Interesting!  This is dumb, but I wasn't even familiar with "map" being available at the core JavaScript level (rather than using the external "async" module).  Most of my JavaScript development thus far has been in the browser, and I'm accustomed to using jQuery for everything to avoid as many browser-specific issues as possible.  With Node, it's nice to have some certainty as to which features the VM does and doesn't support!

Comment: Basically for my immediate purposes, I can just use a core JavaScript "map()" to perform the pluck operation synchronously (the array sizes will be very small)... and sidestep the need to complicate the surrounding promise chain any further.

Comment: @StevePerkins: Sure, if you only want to perform a pluck operation you neither need promises nor `async` :-)

Comment: Heh.  True, but the code snippet here exists inside the larger context of a `then()` promise chain.  That was basically the gist of my question... since I was using Q to manage than larger flow, could I avoid an extra module dependency by using Q to manage this particular operation inside of the larger flow?  However, it turns out that this particular operation doesn't need any asynchronous management at all... making the original question moot for my immediate purposes.  Your example will still come in handy for more complex cases.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, `Bluebird` instead of `Q` supports the `join()` function.