# Do something async with underscore map

Tags: node.js, promise, underscore.js, q

```
function addSomething(data) {
    var defer = q.defer();
    data = _.map(data, function(item) {
            item['something'] = callSomethingAsync();
            return item;
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

How can I handle this problem. The only way I found is using Async.js.
But maybe there is a better way using $q?

EDIT:

```
function getScopes(item) {
    var defer = q.defer();
    var query = "SELECT somevalue FROM Something WHERE ID = '" + item.id + "'";
    mysql.query(query, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        } else {
            item[newkey] = data
            defer.resolve(item);
        }
    });
    defer.resolve(data)
    return defer.promise;
}

//add necessary scopes to the audit
function addScopes(data) {
    var promises = _.map(data, function(item) {
        return getScopes(item);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

How I can prevent using defer in the getScopes function?

Edit 2:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM tiscope";
Q.nfcall(mysql.query, query).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

there is nothing returned.

Here is how I use mysql:

```
var sql = require('mysql');

var connection = sql.createConnection({
    host     : 'xxx',
    user     : 'xxx',
    password : 'xxx',
    database : 'xxx'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log('mysql connection established');
    }
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Maybe there is the mistake.

Comment: You could just make the first promise wait for "array" of promises to resolve before resolving the first one (using promise.all for example) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: But then I can't use map? I just can return an array of result and have to merge them?

Comment: Aside from the use of `defer` and the mutation of the data array the idea presented seem reasonable. How is `callSomethingAsync` implemented? Does it take a callback? Is it synchronous because it returns a value? Is it a generator function?

Comment: The more I look at the code the use of `map` to mutate the data structure is very disturbing. First why is `data` being mutated? And if the intent is to mutate the items an `each` would be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a pure Promise-based approach for mapping/concatenating collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017980/is-there-a-pure-promise-based-approach-for-mapping-concatenating-collections)

Comment: @robert my point was that what you are facing is just nested promises. it might look intimidating but there is nothing more complicated than what you had written in your example. start by separating the code to separate functions that each of them is returning a promise and wire them all together. everything will eventually become simple and clear to you, i promise ;-)

Comment: @BenYitzhaki I edited first post...maybe you can help to seperate that?

Comment: @Sukima thanks for example. I hope the edit shows my structure in a better way? Or I do the thinks in a unecessary complex way?

Comment: [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/sukima/a4cd15f663aa04106308745d269d8eb4) Shows two examples on how to accomplish this with Q.

Comment: @Sukima: Can't get it work. I isolate Q.nfcall for testing. Maybe you can help another time. I updated first post.

Comment: Are you using `Q` or `$q`? They're very different libraries.

Comment: I use: npm install q - should be this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/q require: var Q = require('q');

Comment: My guess is you have a fundamental design flaw. By the looks of things your mixing callbacks with promises with synchronous assumptions. There is a lack of consistent API ussage in your code examples. I’d say the problem lies with mixing async code with sync assumptions. Anf that is beyond the scope of this SO question.

Comment: ok, but I thnink nfcall is to handle callbacks with promises? But it did not work?

Comment: @Sukima I make a Gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5428ddc160a160e1c0fe3cb96ca3db1a maybe you can help me to fix design fails. But isn't it normal to mix asyn and snc code? the example work for me.

Comment: @robert lets move the conversation to https://gist.github.com/sukima/2e53c7df68303eb1f1738cd4b21ed571 since that code review is out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Sukima Ok, I have joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of promise libraries provide a `map` function. Seems Q does not. No matter the the same can be accomplished with vanilla promises (and Q) anyway using the `all` function.

First things first. Avoid `defer`. It makes code more difficult to reason and maintain. There are only a few rare cases when defer is needed. The rest of the time a normal promise constructor/helper functions will work better.

#### Normal Promises Example

```
function addSomething() {
  var promises = _.map(data, function(item) {
    return callSomethingAsync(item);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

#### Q Promises Example

```
function addSomething() {
  var promises = _.map(data, function(item) {
    return callSomethingAsync(item);
  });
  return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Presumably `callSomethingAsync` returns a promise. If not use the promise constructor pattern:

```
function toPromise(asyncFn, args) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function callback(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    }
    asyncFn(callback, args);
  });
}

function addSomething() {
  var promises = _.map(data, function(item) {
    return toPromise(callSomethingAsync, item);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I edited question. No idea how prevent using defer?

Comment: Try [Q.Promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver) And here is why `defer` is an anti-pattern: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern

Comment: thanks for sharing links and code! They are very helpful.